# Why do respirators have separate inhalation and exhalation valves?

Tags: face-mask-respirator

Thinking mostly of the elastomeric reusable respirators like 3M 6200, 3M 6800. Why not just exhale through the filters? Then it protects both ways. Would that be a problem?

Comment: Those respirators aren't intended for medical use. There's no reason to filter exhaled air.